# Ignore the "No such file or directory" error while executing bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have this bash script and I want to ignore the "No such file or directory" error, when the folder is empty, so the script can execute the rest of the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

TEMP_HDFS=$1

mkdir -p Data_in

hdfs dfs -copyToLocal $TEMP_HDFS/input/files/*.csv Data_in/file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate and proceed with your operation.

```
[ -d "Data_in" ] && echo "Directory Data_in exists." || mkdir -p Data_in
```

And if you want to ignore the error

Try redirecting your STDERR to output as below

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal $TEMP_HDFS/input/files/*.csv Data_in/file.csv 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: But beware, you'll not be able to capture any other errors as well.

Comment: The whole point of the `-p` option to `mkdir` is to eliminate the need to check if `Data_in` exists first. The problem the OP is referring to likely stems from the case where the pattern doesn't expand, and the literal string `.../input/files/*.csv` is passed to `hdfs`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, this only silences the error, but still breaks. I changed it to `hdfs dfs -copyToLocal $TEMP_HDFS/input/files/* Data_in/*` to not specifically search for `.csv`, but again breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal $TEMP_HDFS/input/files/*.csv Data_in/file.csv
```

to just evaluate to

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal Data_in/file.csv
```

if there are no CSV files in `$TEMP_HDFS/input/files`, add this at the beginning of your script:

```
shopt +s nullglob
```

[`nullglob`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) tells bash to behave sanely when the glob pattern finds nothing.